GitHub Throttling while using OAuth Apps with TOTP authorization
We Use Github OAuth Apps to use Github APIs. We have enabled TOTP to handle authentication. Suddenly today we were being throttled while trying to do authorization with TOTP. Message was We were unable to authenticate your request because too many codes have been submitted. Please wait a few minutes and contact support if you continue to have problems. 
Even though Error was gone after around half an hour. I am curious what could be the reason for this. I searched online and also read Github doc on rate limit. I don't see this error anywhere.
Thanks for any suggestion you might have.

The May 2024 article "Securing millions of developers through 2FA" illustrates the GitHub effort to promote (even impose since Q1. 2023) 2FA for all developers.
This is done incrementally:

Looking ahead, we’re evaluating how we can require even more GitHub.com users to enroll in 2FA during 2024, while continuing to monitor and improve the user experience.

It is possible last Sept. 24th (2024), you experience a momentary degraded user experience because of that effort.
The discussion need hints for GitHub 2FA does state:

If you play too fast with testing 2FA, GitHub will throw

We were unable to authenticate your request because too many codes have been submitted.
Please wait a few minutes and contact support if you continue to have problems."


If your IDE failed to authenticate, and retried too much, that could have indirectly impacted your GitHub OAuth Apps.
